# Can someone please give me an example of a Java method which is referentially transparent?

Tags: java

I know that A method is referentially transparent if its return value (with identical actual parameters) is independent of the program context.

e.g. this code is not transparent.

```
public static int Erna () {
  return y;
}
```

but can someone please give an example of java code which is transparent so I can understand this better?

Comment: Related (with examples in some answers): [What is referential transparency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/210835/1065197)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int addOne(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

is a referentially transparent method - `addOne(2)` can be replaced by `3` without affecting the program's behaviour.

Note that referential transparency is a high-level concept, not a language feature (at least in Java).