# In Haskell, what is the analogous pattern to setting up "objects" with constructors?

Tags: haskell

In object oriented programming languages you often have multiple constructors that set up objects of a class, for example a `MyInteger` object could be constructed from an built-in int or a string:

```
class MyInteger {
    int _value;

    MyInteger (int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    MyInteger (String value) {
        _value = String.parseInt(value);
    }
}
```

**What would be the idomatic way to do this in Haskell?** As far as I understand in Haskell the sum type

```
data MyInteger = Integer Int | String String
```

is either an `Integer` or `String` and not a single type like in the oo-example above. And I can't define a logic for the value constructor `String` that would take a `String` and "return" a `MyInteger`.

Do I have to define separate functions like this:

```
myIntegerFromString :: String -> MyInteger
myintegerFromString inputString = ...<parsing logic on inputString>....
```

and then call it whenever I want to create a `MyInteger` from a string

```
 main = do
     ...
     let aMyInteger = myIntegerFromString "4"
     ...
```

**Addendum**:
The creation of an "object" from `Int` and `String` was merely meant as a minimal example. I am more interested in the general approach of having variables of a type X that can be created from various other types Y,Z,... and how this would be solved in Haskell. Precisely because I don't want to misuse Haskell while thinking in object-oriented ways, I am asking for an idiomatic pattern to model this in Haskell. This is why a solution that solves the parsing of `Int`s from `String`s is too specific.

Comment: _"Do I have to define separate functions (...)"_  Yes. These are called [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `MyInteger` always contains an `int` but is sometimes constructed from a `String` by parsing the string into an int first. This is not equivalent to `data MyInteger = Integer Int | String String` but to `newtype MyInteger = MyInteger Int` with a [smart constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) for constructing from a string:

```
newtype MyInteger = MyInteger Int

mkMyIntegerStr :: String -> MyInteger
mkMyIntegerStr = MyInteger . read
```

with the caveat that not all strings have a valid parse as an int and that acknowledging this failure mode in the type system would be more robust:

```
mkMyIntegerStr :: String -> Maybe MyInteger
mkMyIntegerStr = fmap MyInteger . readMaybe
```

with [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from the `Text.Read` module.

In general, though, I think it is best to approach Haskell with fresh eyes rather than to try to map familiar concepts from OOP onto it. Trying to treat FP as a weird form of OOP has lead many learners astray.

Comment: Hi Rein, thank you for your answer. I added an addendum emphasizing that I am indeed interested in a general, idiomatic approach to do this in Haskell.

Comment: Creating an `X` from a `Y` is what functions do. If you have an `X` and you want a `Y`, write a function of type `X -> Y` and apply it to your `X`.

Comment: I haven't worked through the answers thoroughly yet, so maybe you already mentioned it, but what "puts me off" in the mere creation of functions is that they are not "bundled" with the type. I understand that the image of a functions creates a relation between the function and the type. Is that all there is?  The only other thing I can come up with is to also use a typeclass as a constraint. Maybe it's just the oo thinking that makes we want to bundle it all in one place.

Comment: If that is what puts you off then the only solution is to stop thinking about it that way. "Bundling the functions with the type" is OOP thinking.

Comment: (I mixed up my Xs and Ys a bit there, oops)

Comment: This doesn't mean that there's no way of organizing similar functions and types together. That's what modules are for.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell programmers use the ['smart constructor'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) pattern to do this. To be clear, this isn't a design *choice*, this is a design *necessity*. It is simply not possible to do exactly what you do in your OOP example in Haskell.

In fact, you can see this style in the [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html) module. Here's the raw definition of the `Text` type:

```
data Text = Text
    {-# UNPACK #-} !A.Array
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
    {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
    deriving (Typeable)
```

I wouldn't want to touch that even if I were an expert. However, there is a nice little smart constructor right there: (though admittedly it doesn't perform checks)

```
pack :: String -> Text
pack = unstream . S.map safe . S.streamList -- Scary internals handled cleanly.
```

But why don't we have this kind of object-oriented style built in? Because the internal workings of the constructor is hidden from you, you don't know exactly what might be going on when you write `new MyInteger("123")`. This is in direct violation of one of Haskell's fundamental principles, *Referential Transparency*.

So instead, a Haskell programmer would probably translate the above class as:

```
newtype MyInteger = MyInteger Integer

parseMyInteger :: String -> MyInteger
parseMyInteger = -- (whatever implementation here)
```

In conclusion, forget object-oriented programming when writing Haskell (except if you're [being experimental](https://github.com/andorp/oo-haskell/blob/master/src/Store.hs)). Haskell has an entirely different paradigm, so use that instead of OOP concepts.

---

Some optional reading: [What is referential transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210835/what-is-referential-transparency)