# how functions are called selectively in Scala

Tags: scala

In `Scala`, I have seen examples like the following in which a function is called if the previous function fails. But how does it work? Eg, below, if `find` is successful, `map` is called but if `find` fails, `recover` is called. From syntax perspective, it looks that `map` and `recover`, both will be called.

```
userService.find(id).map { user =>
      Ok(success(user.toJson))
    }.recover { case e =>
      errors.toResult(e) // this returns the appropriate result
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, i think find(id) is returning you Future[Option[user]]? or the find method is user defined? which return Future[user] or exception!

Comment: I just picked the example from SO. But in general you could see such function compositions everywhere in Scala, eg. map and recover in future where map is called if Future returns value and recover is called if Future throws an exception. How one creates such function?

Comment: Ok so by the code i can infer that find(id) will return Future[User] or Future[Exception] now you will have to do .map or onComplete or any call back which will be called after the future is completed then you have case Success or Failure in this code we are using recover in case of Failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that functions are selectively called but rather those functions are always called but with their responsibility being same and [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210871/432903) all the time.

Let's say I have my own `Functor` called `MyFunctor` with `map` and `recover`.

- I will write `map: A => MyFunctor[B]` in a such a way that if the current result is good (`A`), then apply the function if not, return the alternative result
- `recover` would be `Throwable => Myfunctor[B]`

Example,

```
  class MyFunctor[+A] {

    import MyFunctor._

    def map[B](fn: A => B): MyFunctor[B] = {
      this match {
        case Good(a) => Good(fn(a))
        case Bad(b) => Bad(b)
      }
    }

    def recover[B >: A](fn: PartialFunction[Throwable, B]): MyFunctor[B] = {
      this match {
        case Bad(b) if fn.isDefinedAt(b) => Good(fn(b))
        case _ => this
      }
    }
  }

  object MyFunctor {

    case class Good[A](data: A) extends MyFunctor[A]

    case class Bad[A](data: Throwable) extends MyFunctor[A]

  }
```

Now you can chain on `map` and `recover`. Both `map`, and `recover` are called but they do what they should.

```
val good = Good(1000).map(_ * 2).recover { case a: Throwable => 11 }
println(good) //Good(2000)

val bad = MyFunctor.Bad[Int](new Exception("error")).map(a => a * 2).recover {
  case e: Throwable => 8
}

println(bad) // Good(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `find` returns not a `User`, but a `Future[User]`.

`Future[User]` can be either `DefaultPromise[User]` or `never`.

`Future`'s `map(..)` and `recover(..)` redirect to `Try`'s `map(..)` and `recover(..)` via `Future`'s `transform(..)`. And the `transform(..)` is defined differently for both cases.

```
trait Future[+T] extends Awaitable[T] {
  def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = transform(_ map f)
  def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U] = 
    transform { _ recover pf }
  def transform[S](f: Try[T] => Try[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
  //...
}

private[concurrent] trait Promise[T] extends scala.concurrent.Promise[T] with scala.concurrent.Future[T] {
  override def transform[S](f: Try[T] => Try[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    val p = new DefaultPromise[S]()
    onComplete { result => p.complete(try f(result) catch { case NonFatal(t) => Failure(t) }) }
    p.future
  }
  //...
}

class DefaultPromise[T] extends AtomicReference[AnyRef](Nil) with Promise[T] { /*...*/ }

final object never extends Future[Nothing] {
  override def transform[S](f: Try[Nothing] => Try[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = this
  //...
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala

`Try[User]` can be either `Failure[User]` or `Success[User]`. And `map(..)` and `recover(..)` are defined there differenty for both cases.

```
sealed abstract class Try[+T] extends Product with Serializable {
  def map[U](f: T => U): Try[U]
  def recover[U >: T](@deprecatedName('f) pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U]
  //...
}

final case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends Try[T] {
  override def map[U](f: T => U): Try[U] = this.asInstanceOf[Try[U]]
  override def recover[U >: T](@deprecatedName('rescueException) pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U] =
    try { if (pf isDefinedAt exception) Success(pf(exception)) else this } catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
  //...
}

final case class Success[+T](value: T) extends Try[T] {
  override def map[U](f: T => U): Try[U] = Try[U](f(value))
  override def recover[U >: T](@deprecatedName('rescueException) pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U] = this
  //...
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala

So basically all cases are dealt with:

- when 1st call is success (then 2nd call is trivial, you can see above that implementation of `recover(..)` for `Success` is trivially just `this`)
- when 1st call is failure but 2nd is success
- when both calls are failures

Maybe you should read more about `Try`, `Future` and other monads, monadic chaining of calculations etc.

[Error Handling With Try](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html)

[Welcome to the Future](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html)

[Promises and Futures in Practice](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html)

[Futures and Promises](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember is that functions are objects just like any other data. So you can pass a function to another function without actually calling it. A function that takes a function as an argument is known as a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), sometimes abbreviated to `HOF`.

In this case both `map` and `recover` are higher-order functions; they take a single argument which is a function. Both `map` and `recover` are indeed executed, but they don't immediately execute the function that you give them. In normal usage the function passed to `map` will be called if the `find` succeeds and the function passed to `recover` will be called if the `find` fails. The exact behaviour depends on which object is returned by that `find` call.