# What is the correct term to describe a procedure that produces the same result irrespective of how many times it is run?

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, terminology, conceptual

Say you want to create a new table in a database. If you run a script that only contains the `CREATE...` code, then it will work the first time, but crash if run again, since it will be trying to create an object that already exists. By adding `IF EXISTS ...` logic (or `DROP TABLE ...`)  first however, you can avoid such errors.

I know there is a specific technical term that describes this concept or property, i.e. the ability of a script to be run multiple times without changing the end result from the result of running the script only once, but I can not seem to recall it, and I have not been able to find it. *Multi-something-something?* or *poly-something-something*?

Comment: Do you mean DETERMINISTIC?

Comment: Thanks, but no - there I know for a fact that there is some special term that has the specific meaning described above.

Comment: @Kjartan . . . I think jarlh is correct.  "DETERMINISTIC" captures that notion at least for SQL stored procedures.  I use the term "stable" for queries that have `ORDER BY` with unique keys, but that is specific to sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) operations

> can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the
>   initial application.

For example, function `f` is [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561780/5205022) if for *all* inputs `x` it holds

```
f(x) == f(f(x))
```

I have often encountered the concept within the context of [idempotent HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016234/what-is-idempotency-in-http-methods), and within the context of functional programming as [referential transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210835/what-is-referential-transparency).