# Is there a name for a function that becomes a NOOP after first call?

Tags: terminology, no-op

Is there a name for a function that should only be called once, but can safely be called multiple times without knowledge of whether it has been called before (i.e. it becomes a NOOP after the first call)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct term to describe a procedure that produces the same result irrespective of how many times it is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199210/what-is-the-correct-term-to-describe-a-procedure-that-produces-the-same-result-i)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the word [*idempotent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), which refers in general to an operation where doing it several times has the same result as doing it once.