# Is this a pure function?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

Most [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) define a pure function as having the following two properties:

1. Its return value is the same for the same arguments.
2. Its evaluation has no side effects.

It is the first condition that concerns me. In most cases, it's easy to judge. Consider the following JavaScript functions (as shown in [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe/))

Pure:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y;

add(2, 4); // 6
```

Impure:

```
let x = 2;

const add = (y) => {
  return x += y;
};

add(4); // x === 6 (the first time)
add(4); // x === 10 (the second time)
```

It's easy to see that the 2nd function will give different outputs for subsequent calls, thereby violating the first condition. And hence, it's impure.

This part I get.

---

Now, for my question, consider this function which converts a given amount in dollars to euros:

(EDIT - Using `const` in the first line. Used `let` earlier inadvertently.)

```
const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};

dollarToEuro(100) //90 today

dollarToEuro(100) //something else tomorrow
```

Assume we fetch the exchange rate from a db and it changes every day.

Now, no matter how many times I call this function *today*, it will give me the same output for the input `100`. However, it might give me a different output tomorrow. I'm not sure if this violates the first condition or not.

IOW, the function itself doesn't contain any logic to mutate the input, but it relies on an external constant that might change in the future. In this case, it's absolutely certain it will change daily. In other cases, it might happen; it might not.

Can we call such functions pure functions. If the answer is NO, how then can we refactor it to be one?

Comment: Pureness of such a dynamic language like JS is a very complicated topic: `function myNumber(n) { this.n = n; }; myNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() { console.log('impure'); return this.n; }; const n = new myNumber(42); add(n, 1);`

Comment: Purity means you can replace the function call with its result value at code level without changing the behavior of your program.

Comment: To go a bit further about what constitutes a side effect, and with more theoretical terminology, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116377/what-is-meant-when-we-say-that-divergence-is-the-only-side-effect-of-the-lambda

Comment: Today, the function is `(x) => {return x * 0.9;}`. Tomorrow, you will have a different function which will also be pure, maybe `(x) => {return x * 0.89;}`. Notice that each time you run `(x) => {return x * exchangeRate;}` it creates a *new* function, and that function is pure because `exchangeRate` can't change.

Comment: This is an impure function, 
If you want to make it pure, you can use
`const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};`

for a pure function, `Its return value is the same for the same arguments.` should hold always, 1second, 1 decade .. later no matter what

Comment: I do think that code with 100% pure functions is a paradox.But, it's good to try to keep things as pure as possible.as long as it depends on something from an external system/is calling an impure function inside, it's impure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is an example of a function which violates #1 but fulfills #2?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The `dollarToEuro`'s return value depends on an outside variable that is not an argument; therefore, the function is impure.

> If the answer is NO, how then can we refactor the function to be pure?

One option is to pass in `exchangeRate`. This way, every time arguments are `(something, somethingElse)`, the output is *guaranteed* to be `something * somethingElse`:

```
const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};
```

Note that for functional programming, you should avoid `let` - always use `const` to avoid reassignment.

Comment: Not having free variables **is not** a requirement for a function to be pure: `const add = x => y => x + y; const one = add(42);` Here both `add` and `one` are pure functions.

Comment: @zerkms That `x` *is* a (curried) argument, though, so it's OK (rather than being a non-argument outside variable that the return value depends on)

Comment: @CertainPerformance "depends on an outside variable that's not an argument" --- I addressed this statement, that's misleading. I can provide an example with an IIFE without currying, that would also be pure yet still not fit your definition. My point is that pureness is about _what_, not _how_.

Comment: `const foo = 42; const add42 = x => x + foo;` <-- this is another pure function, which again uses free variables.

Comment: Both your counterexamples are faulty. For the curried function, `x` isn't exactly an _outside variable_. `const foo = 42` isn't a _variable_ at all. Replace `const` with `let`/`var` - does `add42` look particularly pure now?

Comment: @mbojko I'm not sure what the "outside variable" term means. Could you first define it please? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: Well, for one, "outside variable" should be _variable_. For your `one` function, the value of `x` is set in stone.

Comment: @mbojko totally not a problem: `const add42 = (function() { var ft = 42; return x => x + ft; })()`. Here `ft` is a variable, `add42` is still pure  That's why I suggested to use well defined terms when you discuss questions heavily relying on terminology and definitions. Making up terms on the fly helps nobody and leads to misleading answers like this one.

Comment: @zerkms - I'd be very keen to see your answer to this question (even if it just rewords CertainPerformance's to use different terminology). I don't think it would be duplicating, and it would be illuminating, particularly when cited (ideally with better sources than the Wikipedia article above, but if that's all we get, still a win). (It would be easy to read this comment in some kind of negative light. Trust me that I'm being genuine, I think such an answer would be great and would like to read it.)

Comment: I think both you and @zerkms are wrong. You seem to think that the `dollarToEuro` function in the example in your answer is impure because it depends upon the free variable `exchangeRate`. That is absurd. As zerkms pointed out, the purity of a function has nothing to do with whether or not it has free variables. However, zerkms is also wrong because he believes that the `dollarToEuro` function is impure because it depends upon `exchangeRate` which comes from a database. He says that it's impure because "it depends on the IO transitively."

Comment: (cont) Again, that's absurd because it suggests that `dollarToEuro` is impure because `exchangeRate` is a free variable. It suggests that if `exchangeRate` was not a free variable, i.e. if it was an argument, then `dollarToEuro` would be pure. Hence, it suggests that `dollarToEuro(100)` is impure but `dollarToEuro(100, exchangeRate)` is pure. That's clearly absurd because in both cases you're depending upon the `exchangeRate` which comes from a database. The only difference is whether or not `exchangeRate` is a free variable within the `dollarToEuro` function.

Comment: I worked at a company that solved this issue by employing a Bi-Temporal Datastore. This garanteed that subsiquent calls to the same method returned the same value. So the method would be `function dollarToEuro(dollarValue, exchangeTime, knownTime)`. For most cases, one would argue, a Temporal Database would be "pure enough".

Answer (score 84):

Technically, any program that you execute on a computer is impure because it eventually compiles down to instructions like “move this value into `eax`” and “add this value to the contents of `eax`”, which are impure. That's not very helpful.

Instead, we think about purity using [black boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box). If some code always produces the same outputs when given the same inputs then it's considered to be pure. By this definition, the following function is also pure even though internally it uses an impure memo table.

```js
const fib = (() => {
    const memo = [0, 1];

    return n => {
      if (n >= memo.length) memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
      return memo[n];
    };
})();

console.log(fib(100));
```

We don't care about the internals because we are using a black box methodology for checking for purity. Similarly, we don't care that all code is eventually converted to impure machine instructions because we're thinking about purity using a black box methodology. Internals are not important.

Now, consider the following function.

```js
const greet = name => {
    console.log("Hello %s!", name);
};

greet("World");
greet("Snowman");
```

Is the `greet` function pure or impure? By our black box methodology, if we give it the same input (e.g. `World`) then it always prints the same output to the screen (i.e. `Hello World!`). In that sense, isn't it pure? No, it's not. The reason it's not pure is because we consider printing something to the screen a side effect. If our black box produces side effects then it is not pure.

What is a side effect? This is where the concept of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) is useful. If a function is referentially transparent then we can always replace applications of that function with their results. Note that this is not the same as [function inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function).

In function inlining, we replace applications of a function with the body of the function without altering the semantics of the program. However, a referentially transparent function can always be replaced with its return value without altering the semantics of the program. Consider the following example.

```js
console.log("Hello %s!", "World");
console.log("Hello %s!", "Snowman");
```

Here, we inlined the definition of `greet` and it didn't change the semantics of the program.

Now, consider the following program.

```js
undefined;
undefined;
```

Here, we replaced the applications of the `greet` function with their return values and it did change the semantics of the program. We are no longer printing greetings to the screen. That's the reason why printing is considered a side effect, and that's why the `greet` function is impure. It's not referentially transparent.

Now, let's consider another example. Consider the following program.

```js
const main = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://time.akamai.com/");
    const serverTime = 1000 * await response.json();
    const timeDiff = time => time - serverTime;
    console.log("%d ms", timeDiff(Date.now()));
};

main();
```

Clearly, the `main` function is impure. However, is the `timeDiff` function pure or impure? Although it depends upon `serverTime` which comes from an impure network call, it is still referentially transparent because it returns the same outputs for the same inputs and because it doesn't have any side effects.

[zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) will probably disagree with me on this point. In his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58745231/783743), he said that the `dollarToEuro` function in the following example is impure because “it depends upon the IO transitively.”

```js
const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};
```

I have to disagree with him because the fact that the `exchangeRate` came from a database is irrelevant. It's an internal detail and our black box methodology for determining the purity of a function doesn't care about internal details.

In purely functional languages like Haskell, we have an escape hatch for executing arbitrary IO effects. It's called [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO), and as the name implies if you do not use it correctly then it's not safe because it might break referential transparency. However, if you do know what you're doing then it's perfectly safe to use.

It's generally used for loading data from configuration files near the beginning of the program. Loading data from config files is an impure IO operation. However, we don't want to be burdened by passing the data as inputs to every function. Hence, if we use `unsafePerformIO` then we can load the data at the top level and all our pure functions can depend upon the immutable global config data.

Note that just because a function depends upon some data loaded from a config file, a database, or a network call, doesn't mean that the function is impure.

However, let's consider your original example which has different semantics.

```js
let exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};

dollarToEuro(100) //90 today

dollarToEuro(100) //something else tomorrow
```

Here, I'm assuming that because `exchangeRate` is not defined as `const`, it's going to be modified while the program is running. If that's the case then `dollarToEuro` is definitely an impure function because when the `exchangeRate` is modified, it'll break referential transparency.

However, if the `exchangeRate` variable is not modified and will never be modified in the future (i.e. if it's a constant value), then even though it's defined as `let`, it won't break referential transparency. In that case, `dollarToEuro` is indeed a pure function.

Note that the value of `exchangeRate` can change every time you run the program again and it won't break referential transparency. It only breaks referential transparency if it changes while the program is running.

For example, if you run my `timeDiff` example multiple times then you'll get different values for `serverTime` and therefore different results. However, because the value of `serverTime` never changes while the program is running, the `timeDiff` function is pure.

Comment: This was very informative. Thanks. And I did mean to use `const` in my example.

Comment: If you did mean to use `const` then the `dollarToEuro` function is indeed pure. The only way the value of `exchangeRate` would change is if you ran the program again. In that case, the old process and the new process are different. Hence, it doesn't break referential transparency. It's like calling a function twice with different arguments. The arguments might be different but within the function the value of the arguments remain constant.

Comment: This sound like a little theory about relativity: constants are only relatively constant, not absolutely, namely relative to the running process. Clearly the only right answer here. +1.

Comment: Yep, now I agree I was wrong about judging the `dollarToEuro`. I'm sure my main point still stands though (which was that purity comes from properties of a function, not implementation details).

Comment: Apart from being pragmatic about the internals of the function ("black box"), you should mention that we also need to be pragmatic in defining the semantics of what counts as "same result" (and what a "result" is at all - it might not be only about the return value). For example, we wouldn't care if the things a function returns are stored in different memory locations on the stack - "*that's not very helpful*" as you say. We usually don't exactly care about object identity either. We only care about a certain equality - which is most often only implied, not rigorously defined.

Comment: I disagree with *"is impure because it eventually compiles down to instructions like “move this value into eax” and “add this value to the contents of eax”*. If `eax` is cleared - via a load or a clear - the code remains deterministic regardless of what else is happening and is therefore pure. Otherwise, very comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Bergi: Actually, in a pure language with immutable values, identity is irrelevant. Whether two references which evaluate to the same value are two references to the same object or to different objects can *only* be observed by *mutating* the object through one of the references and observing whether the value also changes when retrieved through the other reference. Without mutation, identity becomes irrelevant. (As Rich Hickey would say: Identity is a series of States over Time.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Of course - but javascript is not a pure language, and identity is observable even between immutable objects with `==`.

Comment: Quoting that famous Rich Hickey quote: `If a tree falls in the woods, does it make a sound? If a pure function mutates some local data in order to produce an immutable return value, is that ok?` :] I like this answer it captures the gist of the issue.

Comment: Say a value is retrieved from a database every time it's needed, but this value is not supposed to change because the database owner said so. So it could change, but it doesn't. This means in theory the observable behavior could be different, but in practice it isn't. How does this affect purity?

Comment: @Burak If a value is guaranteed to be the same every time you fetch it from the database then why would you need to fetch it more than once? Setting a variable to its own value is a no-op and no-ops are pure. Hence, it doesn't affect purity. Note however that fetching data from a database is itself an impure operation. Hence, the fetching is impure but the setting of the variable is pure.

Answer (score 22):

An answer of a me-purist (where "me" is literally me, since I think this question does not have a single *formal* "right" answer):

In a such dynamic language as JS with so many possibilities to monkey patch base types, or make up custom types using features like `Object.prototype.valueOf` it's impossible to tell whether a function is pure just by looking at it, since it's up to the caller on whether they want to produce side effects.

A demo:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y;

function myNumber(n) { this.n = n; };
myNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    console.log('impure'); return this.n;
};

const n = new myNumber(42);

add(n, 1); // this call produces a side effect
```

An answer of me-pragmatist:

From the [very definition from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

> In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the following properties:
>
> 1. Its return value is the same for the same arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams from I/O devices).
> 2. Its evaluation has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams).

In other words, it only matters how a function behaves, not how it's implemented. And as long as a particular function holds these 2 properties - it's pure regardless how exactly it was implemented.

Now to your function:

```
const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};
```

<s>It's impure because it does not qualify the requirement 2: it depends on the IO transitively.</s>

I agree the statement above is wrong, see the other answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749249/251311

Other relevant resources:

- [Referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

Comment: What is the "me-" in "me-purist" and "me-pragmatist"? You? (The article "a" in front suggests otherwise, but...)

Comment: Regarding *"no variation with local static variables, **non-local variables**"*, the "non-local variable" sounds like what I was trying to refer to by an "outside variable".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `me` as zerkms who provides an answer.

Comment: Yeah, with Javascript it is all about confidence, not guarantees

Comment: Me-purist: Technically I'd argue it is pure since `fetchFromDatabase` either returns a `Promise` or `undefined` (callbacks assumed). So the result of `dollarToEuro` will always be `NaN`.

Comment: @bob ... or it's a blocking call.

Comment: @zerkms - So am I correct that your primary point is that it doesn't matter if the function uses non-local variables, so long as the return value it provides doesn't vary? So your function using `ft` is fine because `ft` is effectively constant, so the return value doesn't vary based on non-local variables. But `addX` here would be impure: `const [addX, setX] = (x => { return [y => x + y, newx => { x = newx; }]; })(42);` since it uses `x` and `setX` can change it?

Comment: `addX` is totally impure since it violates #1 with "no variation with local static variables". In JS there is no "static" variables per se, but a captured variable in your example acts like one, since it follows the same semantics like local static variable in other languages: its storage has the same lifetime as the function itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but yes, my point is that it must have certain properties, regardless what language constructions/features have been used. Since what we care about - is semantics/behaviour, in the end of the day all that is eventually translated to CPU instructions most of which are impure by design.

Comment: @zerkms - Thanks. Just so I'm 100% sure, the key difference between your `add42` and my `addX` is purely that my `x` may be changed, and your `ft` cannot be changed (and thus, `add42`'s return value doesn't vary based on `ft`)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, I think so. As long as a value is [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) - it would not break those properties.

Comment: I disagree that the `dollarToEuro` function in your example is impure. I explained why I disagree in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749249/783743

Comment: Beware, that article misrepresents referential transparency. See its link to [a correct exposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9859966/3404097).

Answer (score 15):

Like other answers have said, the way you have implemented `dollarToEuro`,

```
let exchangeRate = fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x) => { return x * exchangeRate; };
```

is indeed pure, because the exchange rate is not updated while the program is running. Conceptually, however, `dollarToEuro` seems like it should be an impure function, in that it uses whatever the most up to date exchange rate is. The simplest way to explain this discrepancy is that you have not implemented `dollarToEuro` but `dollarToEuroAtInstantOfProgramStart` - there are several parameters that are required to calculate a currency conversion, and a truly pure version of the general `dollarToEuro` would supply all of them.

The most direct parameters you could provide, as other answers suggest, are the amount of USD to convert, and the exchange rate of how many euro per dollar:

```
const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => x * exchangeRate;
```

However, such a function is pretty pointless - a caller of `dollarToEuro` will be calling it precisely because they do not know the exchange rate, and expect `dollarToEuro` to know the rate and apply it to their desired currency exchange.

There is, however, something else we know: at any given instant, the exchange rate will always be the same, and if you have a source (perhaps, a database) that publishes the exchange rates as they change, then we can look up that source by date and figure out what the exchange rate is going to be on any particular day. In code, what this would translate to is providing a date parameter to your `fetchFromDatabase()` function:

```
function fetchFromDatabase(date) {
    // make the REST call to the database, providing the date as a parameter ...
    // once it's done, return the result
}
```

If the database always returns the same result for the exchange rate when given the same date input, then `fetchFromDatabase()` is pure. And with such a function, you can now have a function that looks like this:

```
const dollarToEuro = (x, date) => {
    const exchangeRate = fetchFromDatabase(date);
    return x * exchangeRate;
}
```

and it too would be pure.

Now, going back to your original function. If we rewrite it into this new framework of this new `dollarToEuro(x, date)`, it would look like this:

```
const programStartDate = Date.now();

const dollarToEuroAtInstantOfProgramStart = (x) => { 
    return dollarToEuro(x, programStartDate); 
}
```

If instead we wanted to write a function which converts the currency using the most up-to-date value in the database, we would write something like:

```
const dollarToEuroUpToDate = (x) => { return dollarToEuro(x, Date.now()); }
```

This function would not be pure, because (and only because) `Date.now()` is not pure - and that's exactly what we expect.

Comment: @Snowman You're welcome! I updated the answer a bit to add more code examples.

Answer (score 8):

I’d like to back out a bit from the specific details of JS and the abstraction of formal definitions, and talk about which conditions need to hold to enable specific optimizations.  That’s usually the main thing we care about when writing code (although it helps prove correctness, too).  Functional programming is neither a guide to the latest fashions nor a monastic vow of self-denial.  It is a tool to solve problems.

When you have code like this:

```
let exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;

const dollarToEuro = (x) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};

dollarToEuro(100) //90 today

dollarToEuro(100) //something else tomorrow
```

If `exchangeRate` could never be modified in between the two calls to `dollarToEuro(100)`, it is possible to memo-ize the result of the first call to `dollarToEuro(100)` and optimize away the second call.  The result will be the same, so we can just remember the value from before.

The `exchangeRate` might be set once, before calling any function that looks it up, and never modified.  Less restrictively, you might have code that looks up the `exchangeRate` once for a particular function or block of code, and uses the same exchange rate consistently within that scope.  Or, if only this thread can modify the database, you would be entitled to assume that, if you did not update the exchange rate, no one else has changed it on you.

If `fetchFromDatabase()` is itself a pure function evaluating to a constant, and `exchangeRate` is immutable, we could fold this constant all the way through the calculation.  A compiler that knows this to be the case could make the same deduction you did in the comment, that `dollarToEuro(100)` evaluates to 90.0, and replace the entire expression with the constant 90.0.

However, if `fetchFromDatabase()` does not perform I/O, which is considered a side-effect, its name violates the Principle of Least Astonishment.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the points others have made about referential transparency: we can define purity as simply being referential transparency of function calls (i.e. every call to the function can be replaced by the return value without changing the semantics of the program).

The two properties you give are both *consequences* of referential transparency. For example, the following function `f1` is impure, since it doesn't give the same result every time (the property you've numbered 1):

```
function f1(x, y) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) { return x; }
  return y;
}
```

Why is it important to get the same result every time? Because getting different results is one way for a function call to have different semantics from a value, and hence break referential transparency.

Let's say we write the code `f1("hello", "world")`, we run it and get the return value `"hello"`. If we do a find/replace of every call `f1("hello", "world")` and replace them with `"hello"` we will have changed the semantics of the program (all of the calls will now be replaced by `"hello"`, but originally about half of them would have evaluated to `"world"`). Hence calls to `f1` are not referentially transparent, hence `f1` is impure.

Another way that a function call can have different semantics to a value is by executing statements. For example:

```
function f2(x) {
  console.log("foo");
  return x;
}
```

The return value of `f2("bar")` will always be `"bar"`, but the semantics of the value `"bar"` are different from the call `f2("bar")` since the latter will also log to the console. Replacing one with the other would change the semantics of the program, so it's not referentially transparent, and hence `f2` is impure.

Whether your `dollarToEuro` function is referentially transparent (and hence pure) depends on two things:

- The 'scope' of what we consider referentially transparent
- Whether the `exchangeRate` will ever change within that 'scope'

There is no "best" scope to use; normally we would think about a single run of the program, or the lifetime of the project. As an analogy, imagine that every function's return values get cached (like the memo table in the example given by @aadit-m-shah): when would we need to clear the cache, to guarantee that stale values won't interfere with our semantics?

If `exchangeRate` were using `var` then it could change between each call to `dollarToEuro`; we would need to clear any cached results between each call, so there would be no referential transparency to speak of.

By using `const` we're expanding the 'scope' to a run of the program: it would be safe to cache return values of `dollarToEuro` until the program finishes. We could imagine using a macro (in a language like Lisp) to replace function calls with their return values. This amount of purity is common for things like configuration values, commandline options, or unique IDs. If we limit ourselves to thinking about one run of the program then we get most of the benefits of purity, but we have to be careful *across* runs (e.g. saving data to a file, then loading it in another run). I wouldn't call such functions "pure" in an *abstract* sense (e.g. if I were writing a dictionary definition), but have no problem with treating them as pure *in context*.

If we treat the lifetime of the project as our 'scope' then we're the "most referentially transparent" and hence the "most pure", even in an abstract sense. We would never need to clear our hypothetical cache. We could even do this "caching" by directly rewriting the source code on disk, to replace calls with their return values. This would even work *across* projects, e.g. we could imagine an online database of functions and their return values, where anyone can look up a function call and (if it's in the DB) use the return value provided by someone on the other side of the world who used an identical function years ago on a different project.

Answer (score 7):

This function is not pure, it relies on an outside variable, which is almost definitely going to change.

The function therefore fails the first point you made, it does not return the same value when for the same arguments.

To make this function "pure", pass `exchangeRate` in as an argument.

This would then satisfy both conditions.

1. It would always return the same value when passing in the same value and exchange rate.
2. It would also have no side effects.

Example code:

```
const dollarToEuro = (x, exchangeRate) => {
  return x * exchangeRate;
};

dollarToEuro(100, fetchFromDatabase())
```

Comment: "which is almost definitely going to change" --- it's not, it's `const`.

Answer (score 4):

As written, it is a pure function.  It produces no side effects.  The function has one formal parameter, but it has two inputs, and will always output the same value for any two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we call such functions pure functions. If the answer is NO, how then can we refactor it to be one?

As you duly noted, *"it might give me a different output tomorrow"*. Should that be the case, the answer would a resounding *"no"*. This is especially so if your intended behaviour of `dollarToEuro` has been correctly interpreted as:

```
const dollarToEuro = (x) => {
  const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase(); // evaluates to say 0.9 for today;
  return x * exchangeRate;
};
```

However, a different interpretation exists, where it would be considered pure:

```
const dollarToEuro = ( () => {
    const exchangeRate =  fetchFromDatabase();

    return ( x ) => x * exchangeRate;
} )();
```

`dollarToEuro` directly above is pure.

---

From a software engineering perspective, it's essential to declare the dependency of `dollarToEuro` on the function `fetchFromDatabase`. Therefore, refactor the definition of `dollarToEuro` as follows:

```
const dollarToEuro = ( x, fetchFromDatabase ) => {
  return x * fetchFromDatabase();
};
```

With this outcome, given the premise that `fetchFromDatabase` functions satisfactorily, then we can conclude that the projection of `fetchFromDatabase` on `dollarToEuro` must be satisfactory. Or the statement "`fetchFromDatabase` is pure" implies `dollarToEuro` is pure (since `fetchFromDatabase` is a ***basis*** for `dollarToEuro` by the scalar factor of `x`.

From the original post, I can understand that `fetchFromDatabase` is a function time. Let's improve the refactoring effort to make that understanding transparent, hence clearly qualifying `fetchFromDatabase` as a pure function:

fetchFromDatabase = ( timestamp ) => { /* here goes the implementation */ };

Ultimately, I would refactor the feature as follows:

```
const fetchFromDatabase = ( timestamp ) => { /* here goes the implementation */ };

// Do a partial application of `fetchFromDatabase` 
const exchangeRate = fetchFromDatabase.bind( null, Date.now() );

const dollarToEuro = ( dollarAmount, exchangeRate ) => dollarAmount * exchangeRate();
```

Consequently, `dollarToEuro` can be unit-tested by simply proving that it correctly calls `fetchFromDatabase` (or its derivative `exchangeRate`).

Comment: This was very illuminating. +1. Thanks.

Comment: While I find your answer more informative, and perhaps the better refactoring for the particular use case of `dollarToEuro`; I've mentioned it in the OP that there might be other use cases. I chose dollarToEuro because it instantly evokes what I'm trying to do, but there could be something less subtle that depends on a free variable which may change, but not necessarily as a function of time. With that in mind, I find the topvoted refactor to be the more accessible one and the one which may help others with similar use-cases. Thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 1):

As the top answer says, *reading* a *mutable* value is generally considered impure and you can refactor to include the exchange rate. What is not stated is that sometime later you will need an impure function to do real work in the impure world, something like

```js
async function buyCoins(user: User, package: CoinPackage) {
  // Random number generation is impure
  const id = uuidv4();
  // Fetching from a DB is impure,
  const exchageRates = await knex.select('*').from('ExchangeRates');
  // usdFromPrice can be a pure function
  const usdEstimate = usdFromPrice(package.price, exchangeRates);
  // but getting a date is not
  const createdDate = Date.now() / 1000;
  // Saving to a DB is more obviously impure
  const coinTransfer = { id, user, package, state: "PENDING", usdEstimate, createdDate };
  await knex('CoinTransfers').insert(coinTransfer);
  // ...
}
```

Reading from mutable values, or reading dates or random numbers, can be seen to be impure by a very easy criterion. Why do we like purity? Because pure functions can be composed, cached, optimized, inlined, and most importantly *tested in isolation*. This is why mocking is so popular, mocks turn an effectful computation into a pure one, allowing unit tests and so forth.

Testing is a great way to ask if you have a pure function. In your case I might write a test, “confirm that 10€ is 11.93 US$” and this test breaks tomorrow! So I have to mock the side-effect, which proves that there was one. Dates are side-effects, sleep()ing is a side effect, these things have no real expressibility in the abstract world of lambda calculus—and you can see this from the fact that you might wish to mock time, for instance to test things like “you can edit a tweet for 15 minutes after you send it, but after that edits should be frozen.”

## What does pure-by-default look like?

In languages like Haskell we strive for *purity by default*, you can still write your `const rate = getExchangeRate()` line up-top but it requires a function called `unsafePerformIO`, it has the word “unsafe” right there in the name. So for example, I might be writing a Choose-Your-Own-Adventure style game, I might include a file `pages.json` that has my level data, and roughly speaking I can say “I know that `pages.json` always exists and does not change meaningfully in the course of my game,” and so here I would permit myself some impurity: I would read in that file with `unsafePerformIO`. But most of the things I would write, I would not write with direct side-effects. To encapsulate such side-effects in Haskell we do something that you could call **metaprogramming**, writing programs with other programs—except that sadly, today metaprogramming usually refers to *macros* (rewriting source code trees with other source code) which is much more powerful and dangerous than this simpler sort of metaprogramming.

Haskell wants you to write out a pure computation which will compute a value called `Main.main`, whose type is `IO ()`, or “a program producing no values.” Programs are just one of the data types that I can manipulate in Haskell. Then, it is the Haskell compiler's job to give this to take this source file, perform that pure computation, and put that effectful program as a binary executable somewhere on your hard drive to be run later at your leisure. There is a gap, in other words, between the time when the pure computation runs (while the compiler makes the executable) and the time when the effectful program runs (whenever you run the executable).

For a very lightweight example (i.e. not full-featured, not production-ready) of a TypeScript class which describes immutable programs and some stuff you can do with them, consider

```js
export class Program<x> {
  // wrapped function value
  constructor(public readonly run: () => Promise<x>) {}

  // promotion of any value into a program which makes that value
  static of<v>(value: v): Program<v> {
    return new Program(() => Promise.resolve(value));
  }
  // applying any pure function to a program which makes its input
  map<y>(fn: (x: x) => y): Program<y> {
    return new Program(() => this.run().then(fn));
  }
  // sequencing two programs together
  chain<y>(after: (x: x) => Program<y>): Program<y> {
    return new Program(() => this.run().then(x => after(x).run()));
  }
  // maybe we also play with overloads and some variable binding
  bind<key extends string, y>(name: key, after: Program<y>): Program<x & { [k in key]: y }>;
  bind<key extends string, y>(name: key, after: (x: x) => y): Program<x & { [k in key]: y }>;
  bind<key extends string, y>(name: key, after: (x: x) => Program<y>): Program<x & { [k in key]: y }>;
  bind<key extends string, y>(name: key, after: Program<y> |  ((x: x) => Program<y> | y)): Program<x & { [k in key]: y }> {
    return this.chain((x) => {
        if (after instanceof Program) return after.map((y) => ({ [name]: y, ...x })) as any;
        const computed = after(x);
        return computed instanceof Program? computed.map(y => ({ [name]: y, ...x }))
          : Program.of({[ name ]: computed as y, ...x });
    });
  }
}
```

The key is that if you have a `Program<x>` then no side effects have happened and these are totally functionally-pure entities. Mapping a function over a program does not have any side effects unless the function was not a pure function; sequencing two programs does not have any side effects; etc.

Then our above function might start to be written like

```js
function buyCoins(io: IO, user: User, coinPackage: CoinPackage) {
  return Program.of({})
    .bind('id', io.random.uuidv4)
    .bind('exchangeRates', io.biz.getExchangeRates)
    .bind('usdEstimate', ({ exchangeRates }) =>
      usdFromPrice(coinPackage.price, exchangeRates)
    )
    .bind(
      'createdDate',
      io.time.now.map((date) => date.getTime() / 1000)
    )
    .chain(({ id, usdEstimate, createdDate }) =>
      io.biz.saveCoinTransfer({
        id,
        user,
        coinPackage,
        state: 'PENDING',
        usdEstimate,
        createdDate,
      })
    );
}
```

The point is that every single function here is a completely pure function; indeed even a `buyCoins(io, user, coinPackage)` is a `Program` and nothing has actually happened until I actually `.run()` to set it into motion.

On the one hand there is a big cost to pay to start using this level of purity and abstraction. On the other hand you might be able to see that the above allows effortless mocking -- just change the `io` parameter to one that runs things differently. For example, instead of the production values which might look like

```js
// module io.time
export now = new Program(async () => new Date());
export sleep = new Program(
  (ms: number) => new Promise(accept => setTimeout(accept, ms)));
```

you can for testing mock in a value that does not actually sleep, and has deterministic dates otherwise:

```js
function mockIO(): IO {
  let currentTime = 1624925000000;
  return {
    // ...
    time: {
      now: new Program(async () => new Date(currentTime)),
      sleep: (ms: number) => new Program(async () => {
        currentTime += ms;
        return undefined;
      })
    }
  };
}
```

In other languages/frameworks you might instead do this by a large heaping of reflection and autowiring dependency-injection; those work but they involve quite fancy layers of code to enable the basic functionality; by contrast the indirection created by just defining the 30-line `class Program<x>` is already strong enough to allow all of this mocking directly, because we're not trying to *inject* dependencies but merely *provide* them, which is a much simpler goal.

Comment: I am curious why this keeps getting downvoted but I mean I still stand by it (it is, in fact, how you manipulate programs in Haskell where things are pure by default) and will gladly tank the downvotes. Still, if downvoters wanted to leave comments explaining what they don't like about it, I can try to improve it.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that why are there so many downvotes but not a single comment, beside of course the author.

Answer (score 0):

I have questions as to how useful it is to classify such a function as pure, as if I start using it with other "pure functions" there is going to be some interesting behavior at some point.

I think I prefer "pure" to have the implication I can compose it with no unexpected behavior.

Here's what I would consider a "functional core" for this:

````js
    // builder of Rates Expressions, only depends on ```map```
    const ratesExpr = (f) => (rates => rates.map(f))
    // The actual pure function
    const dollarToEuro = (x) => ratesExpr( r => r.usd.eur * x)

    // base interpreter of Rates Expressions
    const evalRatesExpr = fetcher => expr => expr([fetcher()])
````

And the imperative shell:

```js
    // various interpreters with live/cached data
    const testRatesExpr = evalRatesExpr( () => { usd = { eur = 2.0 }} )
    const cachedRates = fetchFromDatabase()
    const evalCachedRatesExpr = evalRatesExpr(() => cachedRates)
    const evalLiveRatesExpr = evalRatesExpr( fetchFromDatabase )

    // Some of these may pass...
    assert (testRatesExpr(dollarToEuro(5))) === [10]      //Every time 
    assert (evalLiveRatesExpr(dollarToEuro(5)) === [8]     //Rarely
    assert (evalCacheRatesExpr(dollarToEuro(5)) === [8.5]  //Sometimes
```

Without types it's a bit hard to make the whole thing stick together.  I would consider this some sort of "final tagless" and "monadic" combination.