# Is noop a pure function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, pure-function, referential-transparency

In JavaScript, we can express a simple noop function like so ([It's the same in Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L15760))):

```
const noop = () => {};
```

It might be a frivolous distinction, but does it count as a pure function?
My initial guess was that it *is* because:

- Referentially transparent because it always returns `undefined`.
- Doesn't cause any side effect.

But if we invoke this function repeatedly (like the code block below that assigns `undefined` to a bunch of variables), wouldn't it eventually cause a different behavior (like crashing the program) because the external state has been changing all along?

```
const a = noop();
const b = noop();
const c = noop();
const d = noop();
...
...
(... until memory runs out)
```

(Or should we just leave aside the question of memory, etc. in this context?)

Comment: By the definition you're trying to use there, I don't think any function would be considered pure.

Comment: noop() isn't changing the state, creating ```a``` or ```b``` or any variable at all is what is changing the state.

Comment: When talking about "pure functions", we enter a theoretical realm where memory is no longer limited.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58744557/251311